# Error trying to send event to webchat client

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot that I have built using the bot framework v4. I am accessing the bot using the MS webchat.

I am trying to send an event activity from the bot to the chat client. I get an error when I make the final call to send using SendToConversationAsync.

The code I am using is identical to how I successfully did this in bot framework v3.

Can someone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong here?

This is the code I use to send the event

```
internal async Task SendSpecialEvent(Activity activity)
    {

        Activity clearMessage = activity.CreateReply();
        clearMessage.Type = "event";
        clearMessage.Value = "executeSpecialEvent";

        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

        await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(clearMessage);
    }
```

The error message is

> "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: clientId"

This is the stack trace from the exception. The error has something to do with the appid/password for the bot but I'm not sure why that is. The bot is working perfectly fine up to this point.

> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<.ctor>b__0() in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\Authentication\MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs:line 71
>      at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>      at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.GetTokenAsync(Boolean forceRefresh) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\Authentication\MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs:line 158
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\Authentication\MicrosoftAppCredentials.cs:line 143
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\Conversations.cs:line 1176
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Connector\ConversationsExtensions.cs:line 241
>      at WestRockServiceDeskBot.Utility.ExtServices.SendClearChatHistoryEvent(Activity activity, IWRLogger _logger) in C:\dev\Personal\WestRockServiceDeskBot\WestRockServiceDeskBot\Utility\ExtServices.cs:line 58
>      at WestRockServiceDeskBot.Dialogs.MainDialog.FinalizeConversation(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\dev\Personal\WestRockServiceDeskBot\WestRockServiceDeskBot\Dialogs\Main\MainDialog.cs:line 174
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.OnStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 166
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.RunStepAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 index, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 188
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 113
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 192
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\ComponentDialog.cs:line 90
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 145
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\ComponentDialog.cs:line 86
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 145
>      at WestRockServiceDeskBot.Bot.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\dev\Personal\WestRockServiceDeskBot\WestRockServiceDeskBot\Bot.cs:line 54
>      at Bot.Builder.Community.Middleware.SpellCheck.SpellCheckMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AutoSaveStateMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\AutoSaveStateMiddleware.cs:line 60
>      at WestRockServiceDeskBot.Middleware.SetLocaleMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\dev\Personal\WestRockServiceDeskBot\WestRockServiceDeskBot\Middleware\SetLocaleMiddleware.cs:line 26
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ShowTypingMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\ShowTypingMiddleware.cs:line 71
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate nextTurn, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\TranscriptLoggerMiddleware.cs:line 108
>      at WestRockServiceDeskBot.Middleware.Telemetry.TelemetryLoggerMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate nextTurn, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\dev\Personal\WestRockServiceDeskBot\WestRockServiceDeskBot\Middleware\Telemetry\TelemetryLoggerMiddleware.cs:line 115
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55
>      at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 167

OK, I found something that works I've change the code to use ReplyToActivityAsync() instead of using the ConnectorClient. This new code looks like this

```
Activity clearMessage = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
clearMessage.Type = "event";
clearMessage.Value = "executeSpecialEvent";               
await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(clearMessage, 
cancellationToken);
```

I would still like to learn why my original code doesn't work with Botframework v4

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to authentication changes to bot framework SDK, in which this can occasionally happen if the app id and password are not set up in the app web. You can ensure these are set up in your app web settings.

[image]

If it is not set up and you need to get those values, you can find out how to do so from steps in [this blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/03/find-your-azure-bots-appid-and-appsecret/).